# Speech Recognition For Cordova Hybrid App

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Can anyone suggest a suitable method to implement speech recognition for a hybrid app

Comment: any progress in this project?

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin may help you
(https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer ).I dont know how much effective these because we didnt use it in production environment.
Here is the sample code

`SpeechRecognizer.startRecognize(success, error, maxMatches, promptString, language);`

`success` returns  a json array with possible matches

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used and it is working like a charm on Android device using ionic Framework:

[ng-speech-recognition](https://github.com/Devniz/ng-speech-recognition)